# ZF2 - Getting route exception on working with Routes by the last "/" of URL

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm working on a clean zf2 project, creating a new module called 'feed-food'.

I've been working on a route and I didn't get it work perfectly.

The issue was i made a main route called 'feed', with a child_route called 'feed-food' with two child routes 'list' for listing with paginator and ordenation and 'all' from get from new actions without params.

The problem is that when I use the URL /feed/feed-food/ it work perfectly. But when I use /feed/feed-food (without / on the end of url) I get a route exception.

```
                'feed-food' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/feed-food',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Feed\Controller\FeedFood',
                            'action' => 'list'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'list' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/[:action][/page/:page][/order_by/:order_by][/:order]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => '(?!\bpage\b)(?!\border_by\b)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'page' => '[0-9]+',
                                    'order_by' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'order' => 'asc|desc',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Feed\Controller\FeedFood',
                                    'page'       => 1,
                                    'order_by'   => 1,
                                    'order'      => 1 ,
                                ),
                            )
                        ),
                        'all' => array(
                            'type'    => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '[/][:action][/:id]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Feed\Controller\FeedFood',
                                    'action'     => 'list',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

The Url Test Case:

```
/feed/feed-food/ works
/feed/feed-food/list/order_by/idFeedFood/desc works
/feed/feed/list/page/3/order_by/idFeed/asc works
/feed/feed-food/list works 
/feed/feed-food  didn't work but it should works.
```

Just need to work this one more case, but i'm missed where is to fix it. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks okay. What error do you get when you visit `/feed/feed-food`?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, because you open my eyes that the error was on a subsequent route of the master route "/feed/". Thank you very much.

Comment: If you found the answer please post it and accept it. It will help other people that might encounter the same problem